# Why Process.Start produces ansi escape codes

Tags: c#, rest, process, output, ansi-escape

I have a strange problem when using System.Diagnostics.Process (on a linux system).

Something outputs ANSI escape sequences each time a Process is started.
The sequence is `<ESC>[?1h<ESC>=` [(DECCKM, DECKPAM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences), but that isn't produced by the called program, I used `pwd` here, but the sequence is created with any other program, too.

The sequence seems to be produced outside of the process, as the standard and error output streams can't fetch it.

**And the strange thing is, it only occurs after I started a web host!**

I build a minimal code example.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

class Program
{
    static int count;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        execTest();

        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().Build().RunAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        execTest();
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        execTest();
    }

    private static void execTest()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            executeCommand("pwd");
            Console.WriteLine($"Exectest {++count}");
        }
    }

    static void executeCommand(string cmd)
    {
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = cmd;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

To see the effect you need a special logging, piping or redirection disables the effect.
And the escape sequences are invisible when xterm interprets them.

Therefore I use `script -c myTestProg output.log; cat -A output.log`

In the output you can see, that the first three ExecuteTests works as expected, but Exectest 4 to 9 produces this unexpected output.

```
Exectest 1
Exectest 2
Exectest 3
^[[?1h^[=^[[40m^[[32minfo^[[39m^[[22m^[[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
^[[40m^[[32minfo^[[39m^[[22m^[[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
^[[40m^[[32minfo^[[39m^[[22m^[[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/jeb/xx/csharp-test
^[[?1h^[=Exectest 4
^[[?1h^[=Exectest 5
^[[?1h^[=Exectest 6
^[[40m^[[32minfo^[[39m^[[22m^[[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
^[[?1h^[=Exectest 7
^[[?1h^[=Exectest 8
^[[?1h^[=Exectest 9
```

My main problem is that my program uses Microsoft.Hosting and calls a Process each second, that results in flooding my log files.
Even when I disable the output logging of the Host by

```
.ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder =>
{
  loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
});
```

the problem persists.

**What causes the output and how to avoid or suppress it?**
Where is the relation between a System.Diagnostics.Process and Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting?

PS: The sequence is produces after Process.Start() and the call program ends, but before the WaitForExit is called, tested with some Thread.Sleep(100)

Comment: Look like colored log output directed to the console.

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, the `info` of `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime` is green, but the `^[[?1h` seems to be [DECCKM - Enable Cursor Keys Application Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) and `^[=` is `DECKPAM - Enable Keypad Application Mode` but why it is produced by `WaitForExit()`?

Comment: Did you try to disable colors using `Logging.Console.DisableColors` to `true` inside `appsettings.json`? Check this issue [Logs include control characters (in place of coloring) in Visual Studio output window when using Docker](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/673) and this PR [Add DisableColors option (#764)](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/pull/772). Or maybe using environment variable `ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS` could disavle ANSI escape characters.

Comment: @ChristosLytras Thanks for the hint, but disabling the color only removes the escape sequences from the `info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]` but the puzzling `^[[?1h^[=` are still present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the same behaviour that you describe with `netcoreapp3.1`.

However, as of `net5.0` onwards it seems that *all* calls to `Console.WriteLine` write the `DECCKM`|`DECPAM` sequence first on linux, no need to `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` first.

I couldn't find why older runtime versions triggered the behaviour only after `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` - maybe something to do with the setup of `ILoggerFactory`.

These escapes enable [DEC VT100](https://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html) `Cursor key mode` and `Keypad Application Mode`.

I guess this is done so that keyboards without dedicated cursor / <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys can use the keypad.

On ubuntu 1804 you can view the escape sequences configured for the current terminal with `infocmp -i`:

```
smkx: {DEC+CKM}{DECPAM}
```

A simple way to stop this from happening is to reduce the capability level of the terminal with

```
export TERM=ansi
```

A netcore app will read the terminal capabilities and skip emitting sequences that aren't supported.

A more targeted way is to remove the offending sequence from the current terminal definition:

```
infocmp | sed 's/smkx=\\E\[?1h\\E=,//g' | sed 's/$TERM/nosmkx/g' > ~/infocmp.mod
TERM=nosmkx; export TERM
tic -o ~ ~/infocmp.mod
TERMINFO=~/n/nosmkx; export TERMINFO
```

Some systems use `TERMCAP` instead of `TERMINFO` but I assume a similar process can be followed there.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions work. But still, I can't see why Microsoft think that it was a good idea in the first place

Comment: As far as I can tell, its for [VT-100](https://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html) compatibility. I'm sure someone is excited that this is finally enabled by default in .net5.0!!